# Multiple Select2 связанные option

Tags: javascript, jquery, select2

поставили мне задачу, в которой я не разбирался никогда ранее, было бы не плохо, если бы кто-нибудь смог помочь.

У меня есть набор стран, состоящих из 262 пунктов у каждого есть кол-во возможных переходов.

Эти странны разделены на три группы:

Группа 1 = 20 стран, Группа 2 = 46 стран, Группа 3 = 196 стран.

К каждой группе присвоена сумма затрат.

**Задачи:**

**1.**

Группы выполнены в виде

```html
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox checkbox-primary">
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="Group1">
<label class="custom-control-label" for="Group1">Group Countries 1</label>
</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox checkbox-primary">
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="Group2">
<label class="custom-control-label" for="Group2">Group Countries 2</label>
</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox checkbox-primary">
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="Group3">
<label class="custom-control-label" for="Group3">Group Countries 3</label>
</div>
```

И при выборе пользователя одной из групп стран (человек при этом может выбрать как одну группу так и все три) они должны добавляться в

```html
     <select class="select2 select2-multiple" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Choose"> 
     <option value="1">Страна 1</option>
     <option value="2">Страна 2</option>
     <option value="3">Страна 3</option>
     <option value="n">Страна n</option>
     </select>
```

**2.**

Далее после того, как пользователь выбрал нужные ему страны
Ему ниже высвечивается сумма переходов по выбранным странам и кол-во затраченных средств.

(Если человек выбрал несколько Групп стран то затраченные средства высчитываются по формуле: сумма с группы 1 + сумма с группы 2 деленное на кол-во выбранных групп +%(равный кол-ву выбранных групп))

Пример:

Группа 1 = 10 рублей

Группа 2 = 40 рублей
(10 + 40)\2+2% = 25.5

**3.**

Ниже имеется

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control mt-15" placeholder="Count">
```

Требуется чтобы человек не мог вписать сумму затраченных средств меньше чем получилась у него по формуле.

**Если потребуется, имеется excel файл со списком стран, переходов и суммами потраченных средств по группам, в ЛС могу предоставить**

Answer (score 0):

Для примера собрал такую верстку:

```
 <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="Group1">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="Group1">Group Countries 1</label>
</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="Group2">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="Group2">Group Countries 2</label>
</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="Group3">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="Group3">Group Countries 3</label>
</div>

<select class="select2 select2-multiple" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Choose"> 

</select>

<div class="selected">

</div>


<div id="transitions">

</div>

<div id="summ">

</div>
```

Массивы построил в таком виде:

```
var arr=[

            ['1','Australia','74067'], // 'группа','страна','переходы'
            ['1','Austria','59528'],
            ['1','Belgium','84858'],
            ['2','Albania','9038'],
            ['2','Belarus','13392'],
            ['2','Cyprus','7559'],
            ['3','Afganistan','8565'],
            ['3','Andorra','339'],
            ['3','Antigua and Barbuda','160']

    ], 
    money_arr=[4,3,2]; // стоимость по группам
```

Код для расчетов:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//по клику на лейбл перезаполняем перечень options
$('.custom-control-input').click(function(){
    $('.select2').html('');

    $('.custom-control-input').each(function(){
        if($(this).prop('checked'))
            {
            var countries=[], group=$(this).siblings('label').html().replace('Group Countries ','');

            countries = arr.filter(function (e) {
                return Number(e[0])==group;
                });

            countries.forEach(function(country,i,countries){    
                $('.select2').append('<option value="'+country[1]+'" transitions="'+country[2]+'" group="'+country[0]+'">'+country[1]+'</option>')
                });

            }
        })
    });

//по клику на option переношу его в список выбраных (для примера, под свои нужды адаптируйте), затем пересчитываем значения
$('select').on('click','option',function(){
    $('.selected').append($(this));
    var props_count=0,props_arr=[],sum=0, transitions=0, resault=0;


    $('.selected').children().each(function(){
        if(props_arr.indexOf($(this).attr('group'))<0)
            {
            console.log('ss')
            props_arr.push($(this).attr('group'));
            }
        transitions+=Number($(this).attr('transitions'));
        });



    props_count=props_arr.length;

    props_arr.forEach(function(prop,i,props){
        sum+=money_arr[prop-1]; 
        });

    resault=sum/props_count+(sum/props_count/100*2);

    $('#transitions').html('Переходы: '+transitions);
    $('#summ').html('Сумма: '+resault);

    });
});
```

Косметику вроде очистки переменных, проверок на пустоту и т.д. не делал, это все уже зависит от вашего кода. Все равно требуется адаптация под ваши нужды, тут концепция и рабочий пример методики.

Comment: Добрый день, извиняюсь за долгий неактив. Ещё актуально разобраться в вопросе?

Comment: @Apelsin2020, да, вполне)

Comment: Здравствуйте, поправил вопрос, добавил все подробности

Comment: @Apelsin2020 уже понятнее. 
Подскажите, выбор Select2 чем то обусловлен? Он предназначен для работы с огромными массивами инфы, когда не хочется ее качать клиенту. 
Если я все правильно понял, то можно решить вашу задачу через ajax и jquery.
Присылайте файл (хочу посмотреть структуру хранения информации) - помогу

Comment: можно сюда mifrilor@yandex.ru

Comment: Вся эта история находится в форме(имеются ещё параметры) с последующим добавлением в базу данных.
Отправил вам на почту файл

Comment: А страны как-то хранятся, или за ними и за цифрами вы ходите в файл?

Comment: Будут храниться в массиве

Comment: @Apelsin2020, отредактировал свой ответ, смотрите

Comment: Ещё раз здравствуйте, не знаю почему, но у меня при нажатии на любой чекбокс select изчезает, а страны вписываются в столбик. 
transitions и summ не выводится

Comment: А вы мой код вставили к себе с адаптацией или открываете в отдельном файле?

Comment: Создал новый файл на сайте, подключил скрипты и css

Comment: @Apelsin2020, отправил вам на почту файл, что собирал у себя, сравните. 
Возможно у вас есть схожие классы или идентификаторы или другие скрипты, которые срабатывают на мои классы/id

Comment: Тут немного другая идея. 
В select'e2 уже будут вбиты все страны из списка, а вот когда человек кликает либо на страну либо на группу, в option добавляется selected
И как я думаю, привязку лучше сделать к id везде. Поскольку на это странице будут ещё select2 и чекбоксы